# Dynamically get the sum of columns and paste in the last blank Columc

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that consist columns that varies in count. Every column has rows that varies in count also. What I want to achieve is to get the sum of every columns and paste the total at the last blank column in the worksheet. I hope that someone could help me regarding my problem.

Comment: Do you want the sum of each column or the sum of all the columns?

Comment: Hi ! I want the sum of all the columns and paste the total at the last blank column


Example:

Column 1 | Column 2  | Column3  | TOTAL

Comment: Do you want subtotals below the data in each column?

Comment: Actually, I needed to get first the total of all the columns and paste it to the last blank column so that I can get the average of the total that I got. 

Kindly note that every column contains multiple rows and the first row is for the column header. I hope  you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following sub:

```
Sub AddSums(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws.UsedRange
        With .Offset(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC1:RC[-1])"
            .Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R2C:R[-1]C)"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

to be called by your *main* code as follows:

```
    AddSums ActiveSheet
```

Comment: Hi there, Here's the thing. I have a listbox and when I choose items in listbox it will copy the corresponding columns from the ActiveSheet and paste it to another workbook. What I want to achieve is get the sum of all the columns selected and put the total at the next blank column. After that, I need to get the AVERAGE of all the sum  that I got. I hope you could help me regarding this matter. @user3598756

Comment: you just 1) add `AddSums ActiveSheet` statement right after the one that copies the columns 2) add `Sub AddSums()` code in any module of the same project

Comment: Here's my code.I don't have idea where to put it

Dim i As Long
Dim colsIndexStrng As String
Dim copyRng As Range

With Me.ListBox1
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
If .Selected(i) Then colsIndexStrng = colsIndexStrng & Cells(1, i + 1).Address(False, False) & ","
            
Next i
End With

If colsIndexStrng = "" Then Exit Sub

Set copyRng = Range(Left(colsIndexStrng, Len(colsIndexStrng) - 1)).EntireColumn
 With Workbooks.Add
copyRng.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value =WorksheetFunction.sum(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
End With

Comment: just after `copyRng.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` and remove `Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)`. And, as I said before, add `AddSums()` code in any module of the same project

Comment: YES! THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! This works perfectly. You save me . Thank you very much and have a nice day ! :))

Comment: Hello again, just a short question, how can I put the average at the top of the column instead at the bottom? Also, if possible, how could I able  to set the highlight of the average to color  Yellow? Thank You!

Comment: "bottom to top": just remove`.Offset(.Rows.Count)` from `.Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R2C:R[-1]C)"`; yellow": after the statement of preceeding issue add `.Resize(1, 1).interior.ColorIndex=6`

Comment: When I remove the .Offset(.Rows.Count), the average won't show at the top

Comment: My goal now is to place the AVERAGE in-line with the column headers and set the color of the cell to yellow

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the range started from row 2. So let's try again; "yellow": after the statement of preceeding issue add '.Offset(-1).Resize(1, 1).interior.ColorIndex=6' –

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! You're so great! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This will put the total sum of all columns in first row of the next empty column.

```
Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your response. Here's the thing. I have a listbox that copy columns that corresponds to the listbox items chosen and then paste it to another workbook. What I want to achieve is get the sum  of all the columns selected and put the total at the next blank column.

Comment: Here's my code: 

Dim i As Long
Dim colsIndexStrng As String
Dim copyRng As Range
    
With Me.ListBox1
 For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
 If .Selected(i) Then colsIndexStrng = colsIndexStrng & Cells(1, i +1).Address(False, False) & ","
Next i
End With
 If colsIndexStrng = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set copyRng = Range(Left(colsIndexStrng, Len(colsIndexStrng) - 1)).EntireColumn
    With Workbooks.Add
    copyRng.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")        
    End With

Comment: I'm still not clear on whether you need each individual total.  You can simple use WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.usedrange) to get the average of all the data.

Comment: Actually, I needed to get first the total of all the columns and paste it to the last blank column so that I can get the average of the total that I got. Kindly note that every column contains multiple rows and the first row is for the column header. I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub GetTotals()
    Dim lastColumn As Long, y As Long
    Dim List As Object
    Set List = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    For y = 1 To lastColumn
        List.Add WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns(y))
    Next

    Cells(1, y).Resize(List.Count) = Application.Transpose(List.ToArray)

    Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns(y))

End Sub
```